# When is INDEX included in Row-Based Binary Log using "full-image"

Tags: replication, mariadb, binlog

### MariaDB Config

version:

```
> mysql -V
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.4.27-MariaDB, for Win64 (AMD64), source revision 0946c99e7d6f7ac9dfcf3e60dae6ae85161d5ef2
```

my.ini:

```
[mysqld]
log-bin=bin.log
log-bin-index=bin-log.index
max_binlog_size=100M
binlog_format=row
socket=mysql.sock
```

binlog_row_image=full (as default)

### MariaDB Tables

I have tested more tables, but I will only include 2 of them.

```
CREATE TABLE `use_all_in_one_btree` (
  `primary_key_1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `primary_key_2` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `unique_key_1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `unique_key_2` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `index_key_1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `index_key_2` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `fulltext_key_1` text NOT NULL,
  `fulltext_key_2` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`primary_key_1`,`primary_key_2`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_key_1` (`unique_key_1`,`unique_key_2`),
  KEY `index_key_1` (`index_key_1`,`index_key_2`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `fulltext_key_1` (`fulltext_key_1`,`fulltext_key_2`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci
```

```
CREATE TABLE `use_all_in_one_hash` (
  `primary_key_1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `primary_key_2` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `unique_key_1` text NOT NULL,
  `unique_key_2` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `unique_key_3` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `fulltext_key_1` text NOT NULL,
  `fulltext_key_2` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`primary_key_1`,`primary_key_2`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_key_1` (`unique_key_1`,`unique_key_2`) USING HASH,
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_key_3` (`unique_key_3`) USING HASH,
  FULLTEXT KEY `fulltext_key_1` (`fulltext_key_1`,`fulltext_key_2`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci
```

### Problem

In reality I'm reading "TABLE_MAP" event that takes place before any of row modification events, but the columns are same for both. Link to MariaDB TABLE_MAP_EVENT docs https://mariadb.com/kb/en/table_map_event

**I have edited question 16.11.2023**

When I "read" changes to these tables (insert/write_row) in binlog, for example using *"mysqlbinlog"* tool. **Table "use_all_in_one_btree" will have 8 columns**, which corresponds to the number of its physical columns.

But when it comes to **table "use_all_in_one_hash" it has 9 columns**, while it only has 7 physical columns. I presume it's caused by HASH index, both of those columns has a type 8 (LONGLONG) in binlog.

tried googling and reading many pages of mysql/mariadb docs but wasn't able to find any information about it.

### Question

How do you tell if INDEX will be part of binlog, is it every HASH index or can it happen for any other index types too? (Wasn't able to test spatial).

Comment: I edited to make it more clear that you are using MariaDB, not MySQL. These are two different products, and they are not compatible. MariaDB started as a fork of MySQL, but both products have changed a lot since then, and they will continue to change independently of each other.

Comment: Okay, I see. Thank you.